# With HTML5, JavaScript and AJAX, are PHP, ASP.NET and J2EE backends still required?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to catch up with modern Web application design approaches.  With the latest technologies, is it still appropriate or necessary to tie a web application to a specific backend language like PHP, ASP.NET or J2EE?

I've been thinking of HTML5, JavaScript and asynchronous queries.  An application could potentially consist of a series of simple, empty HTML document templates where the data components are filled in after the page load event using JQuery/XMLHttpRequest calls to a web service.

In this context, the backend web service could be implemented using any arbitrary framework and the serving of HTML pages could be handle by any web server.  The application's web component would then be purely HTML5 and JavaScript with all other business logic hidden behind a web service interface.

But is this an effective design for complex applications which rely on session management and page transitions?  Does anyone code this way or are traditional backend languages always used to generate the HTML documents?

Thanks.

Comment: You still need some sort of backend if you want stuff like database interaction. Whether that be php, asp, node (javascript) doesn't matter. Also, any "web service" would need a backend. You should look into stuff like Angular or other javascript mv* frameworks (maybe including REST as well). It's pretty much what you are describing.

Comment: In addition to Janathan's comment, you should look in to Separation of Concern [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns . Different technologies will be employed for different functions when building a modular program.

Comment: I don't think the frontend has ever been tied to a particular back-end implementation as such. Whether content comes from an API or a MVC-like framework, that still needs to be developed in a backend language, and one (for the purposes of this discussion at least) works just as well as another.

Comment: I'd add that SPA systems like Angular are great, but I don't think the approach of the GET-POST/submit-redirect site is dead yet `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, I view it as this way.  HTML5 is no longer HTML5.. but "HTML".  We'll never see an HTML6, the new HTML5 model will continue to be improved upon and have features added to it.  Some day, the days of needing third party plugins for video, audio and drawing, all devices will share the same front end presentation model.

When you think of it, frameworks like PHP just make dynamic HTML, and marry business logic with presentation logic.  For the forseeable future, couldn't we always have a need for something like that?  That being said, I can certainly see numerous applications in the future that leverage open data and rich client side controls.  I don't think this threatens the extinction of ASP.NET, PHP or J2EE.. I think it enhances them, as now we all have a more fuller toolbox to develop with.

Scott Hanselman gave an awesome presentation 2 years ago at Microsoft's Build conference (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-027), it's a great discussion on how JavaScript makes the web browser an incredible emulator, and that you can now front load logic and programming onto the end user... similar to what you are thinking.  In the end, I think options like this just allow us to make sure that we use the tools for the appropriate reasons, just like in the ASP.NET world we now have Web Forms and MVC.. Web Forms aren't dead, they're just not the only game in town anymore, but now we can use Web Forms when appropriate, and MVC when appropriate.

Great question!